# How to display a table of calculated dates with records aggregated for each week(s) Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have a table in MySQL database with as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

My Objective is to aggregate the data records for each week. In order to do that, we calculate a week starting from the first day in the table which is the minimum date in the table.

The result table should look like:

```
Period                                Cage         Total NumberOf Items
-------------------------------        
Week 1: 07-03-2016 to 13-03-2016        1                  xxx
Week 2: 14-03-2016 to 20-06-2016        1                  xxx
Week 3: 21-03-2016 to 27-06-2016        1                  xxx
Week 1: 07-03-2016 to 13-06-2016        2                  xxx
Week 2: 14-03-2016 to 20-06-2016        3                  xxx   
Week 4: 28-03-2016 to 03-04-2016        3                  xxx
```

As illustrated above, the Total number of items is a sum calculated for each week in each Cage.

The Start Date is the least date in the table, so we have to add 6 Days to this least date to get the end Date for the first Week.

The Second Week will start a day after the First Week End Date and lasts for 6 Days too.

The Third Week follows and so on and so forth.

I know that using the derived queries, we can get the result but as time goes, the number of dates will grow and the weeks will increase. So my gut tells me that Stored procedures/loops/functions may help.

How do we achieve this result?

```
select 
str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')`Date`,
case when year(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = '2016' then
 (case 
 when week(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = (select week(min(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y'))) from  `tab1`) 
then 'Week 1' 
when week(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = (select week(min(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')))+1 from  `tab1`)
then 'Week 2'
when week(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = (select week(min(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')))+1+1 from  `tab1`)
then 'Week 3'
when week(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = (select week(min(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')))+1+1+1 from  `tab1`)
then 'Week 4'
when week(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = (select week(min(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')))+1+1+1+1 from  `tab1`)
then 'Week 5'
when week(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = (select week(min(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')))+1+1+1+1+1 from  `tab1`)
then 'Week 6'
when week(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = (select week(min(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')))+1+1+1+1+1+1 from  `tab1`)
then 'Week 7'
when week(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = (select week(min(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')))+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 from  `tab1`)
then 'Week 8'
when week(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = (select week(min(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')))+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 from  `tab1`)
then 'Week 9'
when week(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = (select week(min(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')))+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 from  `tab1`)
then 'Week 10'
when week(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = (select week(min(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')))+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 from  `tab1`)
then 'Week 11'
when week(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = (select week(min(str_to_date(`Date`,'%d/%m/%Y')))+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 from  `tab1`)
then 'Week 12'
else '' end) else 
'Not this Year' end `Weeks`
from
`tab1`
```

I have tried using the above code - but its not scalable enough - as the number of records grow and the dates increase - the query wont be of much help.

Comment: Such of functionality is called `aggregate` functions. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html

Comment: Also Maciej Los, I have read about aggregate functions - i dont think aggregate functions will solve my problem alone -

Comment: @ Shadow - how bout you me, using the subqueries? because i have tried using subqueries as you can see in the Question Post!